# Existe diferença performatica entre on encadeado com on com multiplos eventos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sempre utilizei  o on com múltiplos eventos com o pensamento de que simplificaria o meu código e tornaria mais fácil de entender, mas de um tempo para cá me deparei com vários plugins utilizando o on de forma encadeada.

**Exemplo com múltiplos eventos:**

```
$('#foo').on('click , dblclick', function(e) {
  if (e.type === 'click') {
    console.log('click');
  } else {
    console.log('double click');
  }
});
```

**Exemplo encadeado:**

```
$('bar').on('click', function() {
  console.log('click');
}).on('dblclick', function() {
  console.log('double click');
});
```

De forma analítica, existe alguma vantagem/desvantagem de uma abordagem a outra ? existe algum caso que levaria uma ser mais lenta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe diferença de performance, por baixo dos panos ambas as versões viram um simples `elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandler, false );` para cada evento que você passou (onde `type` é o nome do evento), então não importa a forma, a quantidade de event listeners vai ser a mesma no final. Tem também o fator de que existe uma quebra da string para identificar que `'click  dblclick'` são dois eventos, contudo mesmo passando apenas um evento como `'dblclick'` esse processamento da string ocorre da mesma forma.

Sobre vantagem de abordagem, depende do contexto. Nos seus exemplos eu acho que a segunda versão é mais clara por não incluir um `if-else`, mas isso é subjetivo.

Obs: na verdade existe um fator de diferença de performance, a sua versão com múltiplos eventos tem `ifs`, contudo o custo disso é negligível.